# Finding if first image is subset of second image

Tags: android

I am writing Instrumentation tests for my android app. One thing I want to do is to find whether all the UI components are on the screen or not. For that I have taken the screen shot of the complete screen and then I am looking for a particular widget in that image. 
This code need to be running on the device only, not on desktop.

E.g. the full screen shot (image-1) have various android components like textview, button, listview and a image. Now I have a subset of this image (image-2), suppose the image of the button.

How can I find that whether image-2 is part of image-1?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this code is happening from within the application, it doesn't seem like image comparison is the easiest way to determine whether a view is visible.

If you are writing an external instrumentation application of some sort, and this answer doesn't apply, please let me know.

Here's what I would do to test for the presence of UI elements from within the app:

From [the Android API docs on the View object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html): you can find a view by its ID that was set up in the XML file:

`<Button
     android:id="@+id/my_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/my_button_text"/>`

In the App:
`Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);`

Then, check the `getVisibility()` and `getGlobalVisibleRect (Rect r, Point globalOffset)`, both documented on the View doc page.

Pseudocode:

```
int[] viewIds = {<known ids from xml>};
foreach(int viewId in viewIds) {
  View v = findViewById(viewId);
  if (v!=null) {
    bool isVisible = (v.getVisibility()==VISIBLE) && getGlobalVisibleRect(new Rect(), new Point());
    // do something with the visible/invisible info
  }
}
```

Comment: Surely it is great help for me for the applications whose source I have. But in case of only apk how can I compare image. It is easy to compare the two complete images by pixel to pixel comparison, but how about finding the subset, i.e. if one image is a part of another image?

Comment: Google came up with this Java example: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157963-finding-a-sub-image-in-a-larger-image/

There are some more examples, and some advanced sub-image-detection papers, but if you're going for pure comparison that link might help.